# Radio Button List OnClick fires from the text area, giving different result for Check

Tags: javascript, attributes, onclick, radio-button

When I click on the text of a radio button, OnClick fires and shows the currently selected button as CHECKED. When I click directly on the radio button, it fires and shows the button I just clicked as CHECKED. I would expect the text or button to act the same. Is there a way to recognize this difference?

Here is my radion button list:

```
Select Mode:
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadBtnMode" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    BackColor="#CCCCFF" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="3px" Width="130px" 
    Height="16px" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" cssClass="radioWrap">
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="False" Selected="True">Add</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="False" Value="Search">Search</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="False">Edit</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

During Page Load, I enable buttons depending on the user and I set up this confirmation box:

```
RadBtnMode.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ConfirmAdd()")
```

Which calls this Java

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function ConfirmAdd() {
   var radBtn = document.getElementsByName("RadBtnMode");
   if (radBtn[1].checked) {
      return confirm('Switching to Add Mode will clear all data!\rAre you sure you?');
      }
   }
</script>
```

When I click within the circle of the radio buttons, it does what I want, and warns the user that I will clear the screen because they are switching to Add mode. When I click on the text of the "Search" button and "Add" is the current selection, it considers "Add" to be Checked, and puts up the warning. It then fires a second time and functions as expected.

Edited to include output HTML

```
<table id="RadBtnMode" class="radioWrap" onclick="return ConfirmAdd()" border="0" style="background-color:#CCCCFF;border-width:3px;border-style:Groove;height:16px;width:130px;">
<tr>
<td><input id="RadBtnMode_0" type="radio" name="RadBtnMode" value="Add" checked="checked" /><label for="RadBtnMode_0">Add</label></td>
<td><input id="RadBtnMode_1" type="radio" name="RadBtnMode" value="Search" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RadBtnMode$1\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="RadBtnMode_1">Search</label></td>
<td><span disabled="disabled">
<input id="RadBtnMode_2" type="radio" name="RadBtnMode" value="Edit" disabled="disabled" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'RadBtnMode$2\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="RadBtnMode_2">Edit</label></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please give use the OUTPUT (HTML), not your C#

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the main issue is with the server-side code (the confirm actually ask the user if he wants to enter the "add mode"). It may also be an issue with attaching the onclick event on the table itself - this may cause the even to fire before the change from one radio button to the next is finished.

Maybe include the relevant part of what happens as a result of switching between the two radio buttons.

Comment: Yes, the confirmation is about entering "Add mode". If the user clicks Cancel, it prevents the SelectedIndexChanged event from firing. That's the desired behavior. It is firing before the change is finished when you click on the text, that's the problem. I don't know what else I would attach the onClick event to, so I'm not understanding what "relevant part" you are referring to.